# PHP selecting from table not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

i have a problem with mysqli selecting from table. can you pls corect this for me or at least tell me what i have done wrong please? thanks

```
$row = *mysqli_query($con, "SELECT  `user`, `pass` FROM `users` WHERE `user` = '$uname'");
if  ( $row && ['password'] == $pass ) {
    echo "Logged";
} else {
    echo "Incorect user/password";
}
```

Comment: Have you got any error and what is `*mysqli_query`?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please read more at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries `mysqli_query` will return a mysqli_result object. You need to call `mysqli_fetch_array` to fetch rows out of you result object.

```
$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT  `user`, `pass` FROM `users` WHERE `user` = '$uname'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
```